# SOQL ignores : WHERE RequiredLookup__c = null

Tags: soql, lookup, platform-bug

I just figured out, that SOQL ignores null checks on required fields. It seems to expect that required fields can never be null. In my case it's a new field, so a bunch of records actually have null values.

```
System.debug([SELECT Id FROM MySObject__c WHERE RequiredLookup__c = null]);
```

does not give any results.

But as soon as I set the field to NOT required I get my results.

Any one else experienced this?
Any simple workaround?
I don't want to query all records and do a manual check.

---

**Edit:**

Since some of you don't belive it, I reproduced it with a lookup to Account, see screenshots with debugs:

1)
[image: screen1]

switch requirement off and run it again

2)
[image: screen2]

Comment: I am not experiencing this, that seems odd.

Comment: Can you add screen shot of it with debug log?

Comment: i am not facing this, able to get records.

Comment: adding a new required=true field onto an existing database arguably calls for a data migration exercise to populate the pre-existing records with some non-null value

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 The logs just showed what I told you. No results and a list with results afterwards.

Comment: @cropredy True, thats what I was trying to do. It's in our dev org, so we were already testing the field before doing any migration. In the meantime I filtered them manually in a loop and migrated them. But I'm still confused by this behaviour!

Comment: Also confirming that this does not happen to me with a new required number field. Paste your debug logs. Also, check that you have access to the records where value are NULL. Have you done the Query in the dev console? If Dev console works and your code does not, check the API version of your code. You could also be reading the results incorrectly in your debug log

Comment: Sounds like a platform bug to me .

Comment: @Eric I tried it in the code first and as it didn't work in the console either, I switched the "required" attribute off and got a result. I turned it on again and the results were empty.

Comment: @All, I was able to reproduce it easily. Just create a required lookup field to account and try to query all the null values.. Added two screenshots, to prove it!

Comment: @Basti, dont get us wrong. we are just trying to help you.

Comment: May be this is issue in query optimization algorithm which does not considered this scenario. I have seen slimier issue with query not returning proper data due to corrupted index. I would you to log a case with SFDC support.

Comment: Jus adding my thought, correct me if im wrong.
As @cropredy mentioned, Lookup(Required) created restricts null value only for records created after fieldcreation and the existing records will be updated with non-null values. If we are expecting the existing records to be null  then ideally the platform should not allow us to create field(required) for object which has bunch of existing records. You can use CreatedDate of the Lookupfield as a FILTER to query records which has no lookup RequiredLookup__c ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce support confirmed this behaviour and they are willing to fix it. Therefore they asked me to create the following Idea. Please promote. Thank you!

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEPMQA2

A while ago someone posted a workaround below that issue:

```
[SELECT Id FROM MySObject__c WHERE RequiredLookup__r.Id = null]
```

Comment: Strange to me this would require an idea to get enough up-votes to get fixed.  Seems like it is a defect, not a change or new functionality.

Comment: @PhilRymek totally agree!

Answer (score 3):

I was indeed able to replicate this, but it's worth noting that this applies only to required *relationship* fields. That is, if you instead made a null filter against a new, required *text* field then the SOQL query would return the expected rows-I believe this is what led to the initial confusion.

As for a simple workaround you can create a new formula field with a checkbox return type that is simply set to `ISBLANK(RequiredLookup__c)` and then change your SOQL filter to return only records where this field is true.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to sfdcfox's answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306641/soql-bug-for-null-required-lookup-fields):

> This occurs because of an optimization during the "query planning" phase of a query. The query optimizer removes null values from filters on required fields. This optimization allows Salesforce to use standard indexes instead of a full table scan on those fields, which can improve performance by many orders of magnitude on large tables. If Salesforce fixed this "bug," it would drastically harm the performance of virtually every single customer everywhere, and cause non-selectivity errors unnecessarily in many large orgs, just to catch an edge case scenario. As an administrator, you must make sure that your data is up-to-date before you make a field required, or you will run in to this sort of problem.